# Elasticsearch bulk document insert with php curl

Tags: php, curl, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I am trying to insert products to my elasticsearch server in bulk. It works fine when i am doing this via a bash command but when i am trying to do this via php it gives an error

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_PORT => "9200",
    CURLOPT_URL => $elasticHost."/ecommerce/products/_bulk",
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $myProducts,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        "authorization: Basic ".$credentials,
        "cache-control: no-cache",
        "postman-token: 26ce113f-ab54-b1af-aec6-c154d451548f"
    )
));
```

Here is the json layout that i am using

```
{ "create": {"_id": "1"}}
{"id":"1","title":"Title goes here"}

{ "create": {"_id": "2"}}
{"id":"2","title":"Title goes here"}

{ "create": {"_id": "3"}}
{"id":"3","title":"Title goes here"}
```

**Error:** I am getting this error for every single product

```
Response: {"took":1345,"errors":true,"items":[{"create":{"_index":"ecommerce","_type":"products","_id":"14737","status":400,"error":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"failed to parse","caused_by":{"type":"json_parse_exception","reason":"Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')\n at [Source: org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.InputStreamStreamInput@745dc80e; line: 1, column: 793]"}}}}
```

**The command that i am using:**

Curl Command: curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPOST "http://ipaddress:port/ecommerce/products/_bulk?pretty" --data-binary "@products.json"

Comment: You may need to add `content-type: application/json` header. Do share the exact bash command you're using maybe there's something missing from the PHP conversion

Comment: @apokryfos i have tried this but it gives me an error. The error can be found in the description. Also i have added the command that is working for me

Comment: Can you also share how you're getting `$myProducts` data and what it contains , is it the json shared under that ?

Comment: yes that correct. $myProducts contains the json